# Calling a method of an object through a Vector

Tags: object, methods, vector, combobox, jcombobox

This is a part of a larger program that I'm doing where the user can create a Flight object by entering data into JTextFields.  The data is stored into a Vector, called flightList.  On a second panel of my JApplet, the user can use a JComboBox - flightBox - to select one of the Flights that they have created.  When the Flight is selected from the JComboBox, the getPrice() method needs to be called for the selected Flight object, and displayed in a JLabel below.

```
 private class ChoiceListener implements ActionListener
 {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
   {
       //needs to be completed

       if (flightBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
       {
           //flightBox.getSelectedItem(); // returns selected object
           outro.setText("The price for your flight is:");

           int p = flightBox.getSelectedIndex();
           Flight selectedFlight = flightList.get(p);
           String selectedPrice = money.format(selectedFlight.getPrice()) + "";

           fPrice.setText(selectedPrice);
       }

   }
```

I thought I was on the right track, and I've tried a lot of different variations but none seem to be working.
Also, I know that the Flights are being added to flightList, because the JComboBox does display all added Flights.  I've got all the labels set up correctly, I think.  I just need to figure out how to actually get the selected Flight object from flightList using the flightBox, and pull that price value from it using the getPrice method.

### EDIT

From the CreatePanel class (initializing variables and storing the Flight object into the flightList Vector from JTextFields).

```
CityTime departure = new CityTime();                
departure.setCity(dC);
departure.setDate(dD);              
departure.setTime(dT);
CityTime arrival = new CityTime();
arrival.setCity(aC);
arrival.setDate(aD);
arrival.setTime(aT);

Flight newFlight = new Flight();
newFlight.setAirlines(air);
newFlight.setFlightNum(iNum = Integer.parseInt(num));
newFlight.setPrice(dPrc = Double.parseDouble(prc));
newFlight.setDeparture(dC, dD, dT);
newFlight.setArrival(aC, aD, aT);

flightList.add(newFlight);
```

From the Flight class:

```
public class Flight
{
 // Flight constructor and all other variables/accessors/mutators are added here as well.
 private double price;

 public double getPrice()
 {
   return price;
 }
```

}

### EDIT

Completed code:

```
       if (flightBox.getSelectedIndex() != -1)
       {
            //flightBox.getSelectedItem(); // returns selected object
            outro.setText("The price for your flight is:");

            int p = flightBox.getSelectedIndex();
            Flight selectedFlight = flightList.get(p);
            String selectedPrice = money.format(selectedFlight.getPrice()) + "";

            fPrice.setText(selectedPrice);
       }
```

All flightList Vectors have been updated with the  element.

Comment: Maybe the `flightBox.getSelectedIndex()==0` should be `flightBox.getSelectedIndex()!=-1` ?

Comment: Okay I just tried that out but it didn't seem to correct the problem. The error I am getting is that the getPrice() method cannot be found. I feel like in general this code is bloated and could probably be written a lot better..  I understand how to call an element from a Vector, but I guess my knowledge lacks on how to call a specific parameter of an object within a vector.  Yet I was sure I had done this before with ArrayLists... =/

Comment: The `getPrice()` method cannot be found... could you add the declaration of flightList? And the declaration of `getPrice()` in class Flight?

Comment: Hopefully that's what you need.  I've basically scrapped all code for the price display, so from scratch I'm left with:    
    `if (flightBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
    {
      outro.setText("The price for your flight is:");
    }`

Comment: OK, class Flight doesn't seem to be the problem; the method is defined and it's scope is public. Is it possible that `flightList` is declared as Vector, rather than Vector<Flight>? Then flightList.get() will return an Object, rather than a Flight object.

Comment: That was it! I went through all my classes and made sure all the Vectors had their <Flight> element.  Finally it solved the problem.  I also kept your advice for the index `!= -1`  Works like a charm now.  Thank you so much for your help tonight! I can finally sleep well.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked. 'till later!